# Compose form validations

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I have several validation I'd like to add on the same input field. For example, a price field should not be less than 0 ([check](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.16/yesod-form-1.4.7.1/Yesod-Form-Functions.html#v:check)), and another that will query the DB ([checkM](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-6.16/yesod-form-1.4.7.1/Yesod-Form-Functions.html#v:checkM))

```
    <$> areq priceField "Price" Nothing
    where priceField = check validateMinimumPrice intField

    <$> areq priceField "Price" Nothing    
    where priceField = checkM validatePriceFromDb intField
```

So I know how to add a single validation each time, but how can I compose those validation functions together?

Here's a [gist](https://gist.github.com/amitaibu/65eda8b717a23f9d79e7ef94ba43d774#file-item-hs) with a simplified working form.

Comment: hint: `check` and `checkM` both have type `... -> Field m a -> Field m a`

Comment: Indeed, I have noticed it - but I still don't know how to do it ;)

Comment: `check f . checkM g` and `checkM g . check f` are both valid (type-checking) expressions.

Comment: So simple, wow I feel embarrassed ;) I'll add the answer, and credit you.
Now I wonder - if the first check fails, does it stop there, or it continues to the next one?

Answer (score 0):

As answered by @user2407038 in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39414386/compose-form-validations#comment66154006_39414386) , the answer in my case is

```
<$> areq priceField "Price" Nothing
where priceField = (check validateMinimumPrice . checkM validateMinimumPriceInHandler) intField
```

I have updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/amitaibu/65eda8b717a23f9d79e7ef94ba43d774#file-item-fixed-hs) with the working solution